# How to combine data from 2 separate sites into 1 Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client with 2 separate domains. We are combining them into one site with a new site build. I dont want to lose the historical data from the 2 seperate Google Analytics profiles. Is there a way to combine data from the 2 sites without losing any historical data? (One site is an online store and the other is a regular site - we are combining the two).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You could do a bunch of reporting on your existing data and store that information yourself, but that would be a manual process.

Answer (score 0):

As Philip said, you cannot combine domains while retaining historical data for both. However, you can combine sites with [cross-domain linking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en). I'd suggest checking it out.